# WinJS, return a promise from a function which may or may not be async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, winjs, promise

I have a situation where my WinJS app wants to call a function which may or may not be async (e.g. in one situation I need to load some data from a file (async) but at other times I can load from a cache syncronously).

Having a look through the docs I though I could wrap the conditional logic in a promise like:

```
A)
return new WinJS.Promise(function() {  // mystuff });
```

or possibly use 'as' like this:

```
B)
return WinJS.Promise.as(function() { // mystuff });
```

The problem is that when I call this function, which I'm doing from the ready() function of my first page like this:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {

    ready: function () {

         Data.Survey.init().done(function (result) {

            // do some stuff with 'result'

        });
    }
 });
```

When it is written like 'A' it never hits my done() call.

Or if I call it when it's written like 'B', it executes the code inside my done() instantly, before the promise is resolved. It also looks from the value of result, that it has just been set to the content of my init() function, rather than being wrapped up in a promise.

It feels like I'm doing something quite basically wrong here, but I'm unsure where to start looking.

If it's any help, this is a slimmed down version of my init() function:

```
    function init() {

    return new WinJS.Promise(function() {

        if (app.context.isFirstRun) {

            app.surveyController.initialiseSurveysAsync().then(function (result) {
                return new WinJS.Binding.List(result.surveys);
            });
        } else {

            var data = app.surveyController.getSurveys();
            return new WinJS.Binding.List(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this one? I don't believe the 'may or may not be async' is the issue here, I believe the promise setup isn't doing what I'd expect. Can anyone see anything obviously wrong here? Any feedback greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you're doing file I/O in your full init routine, those APIs return promises themselves, in which case you want to return one of those promises or a promise from one of the .then methods.

WinJS.Promise.as, on the other hand, is meant to wrap a value in a promise. But let me explain more fully.

First, read the documentation for the WinJS.Promise constructor carefully. Like many others, you're mistakenly assuming that you just wrap a piece of code in the promise and voila! it is async. This is not the case. The function that you pass to the constructor is an *initializer* that receives three arguments: a completeDispatcher function, an errorDispatcher function, and a progressDispatcher function, as I like to call them.

For the promise to ever complete with success, complete with an error, or report progress, it is necessary for the rest of the code in the initializer to eventually call one of the dispatchers. These dispatchers, inside the promise, then loop through and call any complete/error/progress methods that have been given to that promise's then or done methods. Therefore, if you don't call a dispatcher at all, there is no completion, and this is exactly the behavior you're seeing.

Using WinJS.Promise.as is similar in that it wraps a *value* inside a promise. In your case, if you pass a function to WinJS.promise.as, what you'll get is a promise that's fulfilled with that function value as a result. You do *not* get async execution of the function.

To achieve async behavior you must either use setTimeout/setInterval (or the WinJS scheduler in Windows 8.1) to do async work on the UI thread, or use a web worker for a background thread and tie its completion (via a postMessage) into a promise.

Here's a complete example of creating a promise using the constructor, handling complete, error, and progress cases (as well as cancellation):

```
    function calculateIntegerSum(max, step) {
    if (max < 1 || step < 1) {
        var err = new WinJS.ErrorFromName("calculateIntegerSum", "max and step must be 1 or greater");
        return WinJS.Promise.wrapError(err);
    }

    var _cancel = false;

    //The WinJS.Promise constructor's argument is a function that receives 
    //dispatchers for completed, error, and progress cases.
    return new WinJS.Promise(function (completeDispatch, errorDispatch, progressDispatch) {
        var sum = 0;

        function iterate(args) {
            for (var i = args.start; i < args.end; i++) {
                sum += i;
            };

            //If for some reason there was an error, create the error with WinJS.ErrorFromName
            //and pass to errorDispatch
            if (false /* replace with any necessary error check -- we don’t have any here */) {
                errorDispatch(new WinJS.ErrorFromName("calculateIntegerSum", "error occurred"));
            }

            if (i >= max) {
                //Complete--dispatch results to completed handlers
                completeDispatch(sum);
            } else {
                //Dispatch intermediate results to progress handlers
                progressDispatch(sum);

                //Interrupt the operation if canceled
                if (!_cancel) {
                    setImmediate(iterate, { start: args.end, end: Math.min(args.end + step, max) });
                }
            }
        }

        setImmediate(iterate, { start: 0, end: Math.min(step, max) });
    },
    //Cancellation function 
    function () {
        _cancel = true;
    });
}
```

This comes from Appendix A ("Demystifying Promises") of my free ebook, Programming Windows Store Apps in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, Second Edition (in preview), see http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2.

You would, in your case, put your data initialization code in the place of the iterate function, and perhaps call it from within a setImmediate. I encourage you to also look at the WinJS scheduler API that would let you set the priority for the work on the UI thread.

In short, it's essential to understand that *new WinJS.Promise* and *WinJS.Promise.as* do not in themselves create async behavior, as promises themselves are just a calling convention around "results to be delivered later" that has nothing inherently to do with async.

Comment: Thanks Kraig, that is a superb answer. My assumption was that I could wrap a function in a promise and not receive async functionality, but at least receive the result of the function, I see now I need to manually call the complete function passed in. I missed the call to 'comp()' in the msdn example (it could be commented as an important step perhaps! - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211867.aspx).
Thanks again for a superb answer.

Comment: Your welcome. Promises are not the easiest thing to grasp initially!

Comment: Commenting months later, just to say thanks for explanation.
But seriously, why would someone use that piece of sh**t ? I mean, it's way easier to pass a callback function, which will be called once the function is complete.
I don't see the point of taking a whole day understanding how promise works, then take 2 days writting a working simple promise, just no to pass a callback.
Docs says it helps debugging. Maybe, but it's pointless when you know what you are doing.
I love clear things, clear code, but promises are NOT CLEAR (And as always, the doc sucks)

Comment: A simple callback would be easier in simple scenarios, but the fact of the matter is that programming in an async environment quickly gets more complicated if there's more than one operation going on. Promises and similar constructs (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) allow composition and management of multiple operations, which is a complete pain with callbacks. And be clear that this is an artifact of async programming and isn't specific to JavaScript, WinJS, or any particular solution, so your rants are misdirected here.